# About 64-bit and iOS 8 Requirements for New Apps

Tags: xcode, 64-bit, arm64, iphone-64bit

Apple announced 64bit requirement as shown below:

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

I have been using xcode 6 and My Target Build settings are

```
Standard architectures(armv7, arm64) – $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architectures armv7, armv7s
```

I deleted `arm64` from valid architectures line because I got an error in 64-bit devices like 5s, iphone 6, etc. Can I publish my application after February 1?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to publish your application after Feb 1 if you remove arm64. The statement clearly mentions

> ... new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support

and

> To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures”

What you can do for now is to publish an app before the Feb 1 deadline. The app will enter the review process and may be approved, but eventually you will have to fix all the 64-bit issues in order to submit your app the next time.

Comment: To be clear, does the Feb 1st deadline refer to the time where the app is submitted, and not the time when it is approved by Apple? I'm still waiting for some 3rd party libs to be updated. If I submit the new app this week do you think it would be approved even though it would be after the deadline by the time Apple review it?

Comment: @TheBestBigAl did you submit before Feb 1st? I'm in a similar situation now where I have an app update w/o 64bit support waiting for review and don't know if Apple will reject it if they don't look at it before the 1st of June.

Comment: We removed any libs that did not have 64-bit support in order to make sure it didn't fail submission, so I'm afraid I don't know whether Apple will reject yours after the 1st of June.